# how can i import packages in visual studio code?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, jdom

I use actually visual studio Code ( for Java ) and I need to use Jdom.

For that, I need to import a package/library. I know how I can do this import on eclipse, but how can I do that with visual studio code?

Comment: Where is your code? We can't help you otherwise

Answer (score -1):

A distinct non-answer: you have to **learn** the tool you are using.

The [help pages](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/java) for this product outline how you setup projects:

> Maven, Eclipse and Gradle Java project are supported through Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat, by utilizing M2Eclipse which provides Maven support and Buildship which provides Gradle support through the Eclipse JDT Language Server.

Meaning: in order to work in reasonable ways, you have to define a **project**. Projects provide the required META information, for example: which libraries are needed to compile/run the content of the project.